# Moving Bitcoin in and out of BTC-e

Tags: transactions, wallet, btce

Sending bitcoin to My BTC-e account from CoinBase---I could send Bitcoin to my BTC-e wallet, but I forgot how to recover my BTC-e public address?  My mind is blank.  Duh!

Sending bitcoin to my Coinbase wallet? I can buy and sell bitcoin in BTC-e, but I want to send it to Coinbase. What is the procedure? I have done this, but again I have been playing with different wallets and I cannot think of how I did it! no help from support